# Get last value in a table in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to simply get the last value in my data set, but it seems like all the calculations I've found are extremely complicated.  I have live connections with my data, so my data updates every 10 seconds.  Every 10 seconds, I want my latest value to update.

Example: 
[image]

In this example, I want the measures "Latest Status" and "Latest Alert" to return "Dev. in Motor Control" and "20", respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the lastnonblank function:

```
Latest Status = LASTNONBLANK('Table'[Status],MAX('Table'[Date]))

Latest Alert = LASTNONBLANK('Table'[Alert Status],MAX('Table'[Date]))
```

Hope this helps.